# Java, custom exception not accepted by Eclipse

Tags: java

Eclipse complains about my `catch` statement below

```
public class NaturalLanguageMultiply
{
    public class WrongMultiplierException extends Exception
    {

    }

    private static int toInt( String number ) throws WrongMultiplierException 
    {
        // removed for clarity
                try
               {
                    String numberKey = scanner.next();
                    if ( numberMap.containsKey( numberKey ) )
                    {
                        multiplier += ( Integer ) numberMap.get( numberKey );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new WrongMultiplierException();
                    }
                }
```

It complains about the following catch line:

```
Syntax error on tokens

                catch ( WrongMultiplierException );
                {

                }
            }
```

Also, why does StackOverflow keep asking:Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.  I cannot find the answer in the FAQ or Help.

Comment: SO complained because you had a huge amount of code and almost no text, partially because you formatted *everything*, making nothing stand out as being your own text.

Comment: When I deleted the semicolon it then complained with "Variable

Comment: "Variable DeclaratorId expected"

Comment: Because catching an exception requires a name for the exception.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have read the entire http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html  I have also read the appropriate chapter in Head First Java   I have also read numerous posts and questions on this site  I have searched on the web, all to no avail.

Comment: @DaveNewton The name of my custom exception is WrongMultiplierException ...I appreciate your patience, as you can see I am a rookie.

Comment: No, the catch expression requires a name for the instance of the exception being caught, as shown in the other answers. Also, there's no need to reply with the same text to all the answers. You're having a problem because you've made your exception a non-static inner class.

Comment: @DaveNewton But, everything I have read tells me to do that, i.e. to create a public class.

Comment: I doubt everything tells you to make a public *inner* class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
catch ( WrongMultiplierException );
{
}
```

to

```
catch ( WrongMultiplierException wme)
{
}
```

Comment: When I added the wme, the throw statement just above it complained with "No enclosing instance of type NaturalLanguageMultiply is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type NaturalLanguageMultiply (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of NaturalLanguageMultiply)."

Comment: I have read the entire http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html  I have also read the appropriate chapter in Head First Java   I have also read numerous posts and questions on this site  I have searched on the web, all to no avail.

Comment: You probably got that because you defined a class within another class. Now you're trying to reference it and it's not having fun. Easiest solution is to break out the inner-class to it's own file and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

You have a ; after the right parenthesis of the catch, that's a syntax error.

Comment: I tried that but it then complained with "Variable DeclaratorId expected"

Comment: I have read the entire http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html  I have also read the appropriate chapter in Head First Java   I have also read numerous posts and questions on this site  I have searched on the web, all to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

In this line `catch ( WrongMultiplierException );` you have to add the exception reference name and remove `;`. Correct version: `catch ( WrongMultiplierException ex)`

Comment: When I added the ex, the throw statement just above it complained with "No enclosing instance of type NaturalLanguageMultiply is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type NaturalLanguageMultiply (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of NaturalLanguageMultiply)."

Comment: I have read the entire http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html  I have also read the appropriate chapter in Head First Java   I have also read numerous posts and questions on this site  I have searched on the web  All to no avail.